# AWS IAM Metadata API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I am looking to see if there is an official API for retrieving metadata for information related to IAM permissions, services, etc.

The policy simulator console has pretty much everything I need. Looking at the HTTP requests made, there are requests that return, what looks like, a well defined JSON object.

For instance, to retrieve all of the available services, it calls:

https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/data/resource

and returns (shorted for brevity):

```
[
  {
    "name": "Amazon EC2",
    "actionPrefix": "ec2",
    "hasResource": true,
    "arnFormat": "arn:aws:ec2:<region>:<account>:<resourceType>/<resourcePath>"
  },
  {
    "name": "Amazon Sumerian",
    "actionPrefix": "sumerian",
    "hasResource": false,
    "arnFormat": "arn:aws:sumerian:<region>:<account-id>:<resource-type>/<resource_name>"
  },
  {
    "name": "Amazon Comprehend",
    "actionPrefix": "comprehend",
    "hasResource": false,
    "arnFormat": "arn:${Partition}:comprehend:${Region}:${AccountId}:${ResourceType}/${ResourceName}"
  },

 ...

  {
    "name": "AWS Elemental MediaStore",
    "actionPrefix": "mediastore",
    "hasResource": true,
    "arnFormat": "arn:aws:mediastore:<Region>:<Account>:<Resource>"
  }
]
```

And then for example, API Gateway, calling

https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/data/action?serviceName=Amazon+API+Gateway&servicePrefix=execute-api

returns:

```
[
  {
    "name": "InvalidateCache",
    "evaluated": false,
    "allowed": false,
    "prefix": "execute-api",
    "service": "Amazon API Gateway",
    "serviceAware": true,
    "resourceEnabled": true,
    "deniedByOrganization": false,
    "requiredResourceNames": [
      "execute-api-general"
    ],
    "supportedResources": [
      {
        "Name": "execute-api-general",
        "ARN": "arn:aws:execute-api:${Region}:${Account}:${ApiId}/${Stage}/${Method}/${ApiSpecificResourcePath}",
        "RegEx": "^arn:aws:execute-api:.+",
        "isRequired": true
      }
    ],
    "scenarios": [],
    "contextKeys": []
  },
  {
    "name": "Invoke",
    "evaluated": false,
    "allowed": false,
    "prefix": "execute-api",
    "service": "Amazon API Gateway",
    "serviceAware": true,
    "resourceEnabled": true,
    "deniedByOrganization": false,
    "requiredResourceNames": [
      "execute-api-general"
    ],
    "supportedResources": [
      {
        "Name": "execute-api-general",
        "ARN": "arn:aws:execute-api:${Region}:${Account}:${ApiId}/${Stage}/${Method}/${ApiSpecificResourcePath}",
        "RegEx": "^arn:aws:execute-api:.+",
        "isRequired": true
      }
    ],
    "scenarios": [],
    "contextKeys": []
  }
]
```

This is all of the information I am after. The list of service name and then the actions for each of them, along with some of that other metadata.

Obviously, I want to use an official API that would support IAM credentials and policies but wasn't able to find anything outside of the supported basic SimulatePolicy and context related API endpoints.

Thanks!

Pink

Answer (score 0):

Just as a follow up in case anyone is looking for the same thing, according to AWS support, there is currently no official or supported API to retrieve this information.